# Gibbs Free Energy of Ideal Gas in Carnot Cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, ideal-gas

Let's just say we have 2 moles of monoatomic (maybe helium) ideal gas that is doing a Carnot Cycle with reservoir temperature of 300 and 750 K.

[image]

Now, here's a simple question, what is the Gibb Free energy change from point A to point B and from point B to C in this process? 
Because (do correct me if I'm wrong), I believe that we need to know the absolute value of the entropy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, along a reversible path, dG=-SdT+VdP. But, for the isothermal path between A and B, $$dG=VdP=nRT\frac{dP}{P}=-nRT\frac{dV}{V}$$

Comment: What about from B to C?

Comment: That would involve the S at B (orC).

Comment: Yes. But how do we calculate that? I mean, its not that we need $\Delta S$, rather we need S

Comment: S is specified relative to some well-defined reference state.  We don't need to know the absolute value of S in order to use it in practical calculations.